# Android: How to create exact material design shadow with XML drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, android-shape, android-elevation

I would like to make an XMl drawable file that resembles as closely as possible to the material design elevation found on Lollipop and above. I currently have a shadow that does not even come close as I have no  idea what gradient I'm suppose to use. [image]

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:angle="90"
            android:endColor="@android:color/darker_gray" 
            android:startColor="#ccc" />
        <corners android:radius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
            android:topRightRadius="3dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:left="1.5dp"
    android:right="1.5dp"
    android:top="1.5dp"
    android:bottom="1.5dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

<corners
    android:radius="0.1dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="3dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="3dp"
    android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
</shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Can someone come up with a solution that is at least better than mine? Thank you.

Comment: `exact material design` means?

Comment: In my case, I want the shadow of the search bar to look as closely to the first image as possible.

Comment: Umm, no this is not the same as that post.

Comment: I'm asking how to create this effect with a drawable file.

Comment: read [this](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search)

Comment: @RoderickLord I think you are having problems with ripple and elevation effects,if that's true I think you cannot add them in drawable file. use xml where you have declared the searchview. and also use android.support.v7.widget.SearchView

Also read the link maven mentioned in the comment above that will surely help you.

Comment: Yes, I am using that. I'll thoroughly read it, thanks.

Comment: @RoderickLord add `elevation` to your `searchview`

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I had an `AppBarLayout` which was interfering the whole time against the Toolbar layout so I just removed it completely and it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define elevation in you layout resource file to drop shadow.
 in your layout.xml file it should look something like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/myrect" />
```

Comment: OP is not asking for a `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

For perfect shadow use CardView

**Xamarin**: [MSDN Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/card-view)

To add the Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView package in Visual Studio

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="@dimen/shrine_grid_item_margin"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          local:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">
<!-- Content Goes here-->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Or

**Android**: [Android Devs Source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/cardview)

The CardView widget is part of the v7 Support Libraries. To use it in your project, add the following dependency to your app module's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

XXX

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/ProductEntry"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_margin="@dimen/shrine_grid_item_margin"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  app:cardElevation="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation">
<!-- Content Goes here-->
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```